# Getting error :Error occured while generating Cucumber usage report

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to user cucumber advance reporting but getting error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: Error occured while generating Cucumber usage report
    at com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.reporting.CucumberUsageReporting.executeReport(CucumberUsageReporting.java:385)
    at support.testhi.main(testhi.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.reporting.types.usage.CucumberStepSource.<init>(CucumberStepSource.java:35)
    at com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.reporting.CucumberUsageReporting.getStepSources(CucumberUsageReporting.java:345)
    at com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.reporting.CucumberUsageReporting.executeReport(CucumberUsageReporting.java:366)
    ... 1 more
```

The code I used is :

```
CucumberUsageReporting report = new CucumberUsageReporting();
    report.setOutputDirectory("target");
    report.setJsonUsageFile("./src/test/cucumber-usage.json");
    report.executeReport();
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

error was resolved after updating the version of cucumber-reporting library in pom.xml